# Changing date and time format (ISO 8601) of excel file in core.xml

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to open a .xlsx file using Apache POI. The data format is defined as 
`2016-04-05T07:13:50+03:00` in */docProps/core.xml*. Unfortunately Apache POI does only accept the following format: `2016-04-05T07:13:50Z`.

How do I change this programmatically in Java?

Comment: Upgrade your version of Apache POI? There was a brief bug around timezones, now fixed

Comment: Unfortunately i m on the latest version already.

Comment: Try a nightly build? Wait a few days for 3.15 beta 1 to be out? [This is the bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59183) - looks like it was fixed more recently than I remembered...

Comment: @Arnold , any update?

Comment: @Gagravarr same problem here

Comment: @Md.SharifulIslam Try a recent nightly build, or wait another week for 3.15 final

Comment: @Gagravarr I will wait. I will tag you one more time after one week. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

POI is able to parse Date format 2016-04-05T07:13:50+03:00 in version 3.16

so you don't have to change it programatically